# PHP and $(document).ready() confliction

Tags: php, jquery

I have inherited a website from work and the built in php code is keeping the $(document).ready() function from running in the code. When I remove it, I hit the jquery code, but I need that php code to run the site.

PHP

```
<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'W3C_Validator') ||
     strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'WDG_SiteValidator') ||
     strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'W3C-checklink') ||
     strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Web-Sniffer') ||
     strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'FeedValidator') ||
     strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Poodle predictor') ||
     strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Leknor.com gzip tester')) {
$mime = 'application/xhtml+xml';
} else {
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/xhtml+xml')) {
    if(preg_match("/application\/xhtml\+xml;q=([01]|0\.\d{1,3}|1\.0)/i",       $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], $matches)) {
        $xhtml_q = $matches[1];
        if(preg_match("/text\/html;q=q=([01]|0\.\d{1,3}|1\.0)/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], $matches)) {
            $html_q = $matches[1];
            if((float)$xhtml_q >= (float)$html_q) {
                $mime = 'application/xhtml+xml';
            }
        }
    } else {
        $mime = 'application/xhtml+xml';
    }
} else {
    $mime = 'text/html';
}
}
header('Content-Type: ' . $mime . ';charset=utf-8');
header('Vary: Accept'); ?>
```

The lines following it are:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords"/>

<script type='text/javascript' src = 'jquery-1.11.0.js'> </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src = 'jquery.fancybox.js'> </script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='jquery.fancybox.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='bicep2default.css'/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('doc is ready')
    });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-3725824-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>

</head>
```

I never see the 'doc is ready' with the php code in the script.

What should I do?
Thanks!!

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is requesting we become the webmaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove last two php `header()` lines, and add `<html>` ... `</html>` in your template.